# Bootstrap Spinner Visible on submit

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, bootstrap-5

It's a Django project. I got this Bootstrap spinner in a span in a button:

```
<form method="POST" id="pdfUploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ form|crispy }}
   <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="submitButton">
      <span id="spinner-box" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm not-visible" role="status" aria- 
      hidden="true"></span>
      Submit...
   </button>
</form>
```

And that CSS.

```
.not-visible {
  display: none;
}
```

I'm removing the class "not-visible" in javascript:

```
document.getElementById('pdfUploadForm').addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log(document.getElementById('spinner-box').classList); 
    document.getElementById('spinner-box').classList.remove('not-visible');
    console.log(document.getElementById('spinner-box').classList);
    document.getElementById('submitButton').innerText = 'Processing...';
```

From the console log the class is successfully removed. But the spinner is still NOT displaying. And i can't get why... Thanks!!

Comment: Have you tried setting the `display` explicitly by swapping a class? 

Comment: Ok it's the innerText change that is messing with the SPAN. Not sure yet why....

Comment: @deEr. sorry but i'm unsure what you mean

Comment: Does the spinner show, when you try to set it to `display:block`?

Comment: @deEr. yes it display. But it's really the change of the innertext the problem. As soon as i add this line the spinner is not there.

Comment: Where is the `img` file of the spinner in your code?

Comment: @deEr. it's part of bootstrap
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/spinners/

Comment: Thanks, I downloaded it. Searching... Can you please find out, where the `src` of the image is?

Comment: @deEr. thanks for your help. I'm a noob.  Did realize that the 
   
document.getElementById('submitButton').innerText = 'Processing...';

is removing completely the SPAN tag inside of the button. Here lies the problem. No need to search for the image. But thanks again really appreciated!

Comment: That is what I found out just now too. ;) You MAY use `innerHTML` and copy the spinner plus the Processing... into the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
document.getElementById('submitButton').innerHTML = '<span id="spinner-box" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>Processing...';
```

`innerText` does remove the whole content of the node, as @Maquisard said.

This is *a* solution.